# Using the Unique formula multiple times on User form in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I have created a user form which populates a table, I want this form to basically show the information already in the table as a list. So to do this, I have a Unique list taht the user form pulls from to get the data. The below VBA is what I have used.

```
Private Sub Userform_Initialise()

Dim v, e
With Sheets("dropdowns").Range("I2:I500")
    v = .Value
End With
 
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    .comparemode = 1
For Each e In v
    If Not .exists(e) Then .Add e, Nothing
Next

If .Count Then Me.ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)
End With
```

This code works for 1 ComboBox. I would like to repeat the above for 2 more Comboboxes from other unique lists.

What needs to be changed in the code above to get this to work?

Comment: What range do you want/try processing and what combo Box (its name) to be loaded? You should proceed in the same way, only changing the ranges and object to be loaded. I asked about the ranges to see if it is possible to use the same iteration for loading more dictionaries...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Subroutine that fills one ComboBox with the values of one Range and call this routine 3 times. You can see that the logic to fill didn't change and the only difference is that you pass the range and the comboBox as parameter. Just adapt the ranges and the names of the comboboxes to your needs.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("dropdowns")
        FillCombo .Range("I2:A500"), Me.ComboBox1
        FillCombo .Range("J2:J500"), Me.ComboBox2
        FillCombo .Range("K2:K500"), Me.ComboBox3
    End With            
End Sub

Sub FillCombo(r As Range, combobox As Control)
    Dim v, e
    v = r.Value

    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        .comparemode = 1
        For Each e In v
            If Not .exists(e) Then .Add e, Nothing
        Next
        If .Count Then combobox.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: HI, thank you for the reply, I've tried the above code and made changes were necessary, however I get a "Runtime error '70: Permission Denied" error. Googling this says is a write protect issue, however the sheet "dropdown" isn't protection in my excel.

Comment: Are you sure that the "permission denied" error is thrown when you fill the combo boxes? Which row exactly throws that error?

Comment: Ahh ok, I was trying to run the script from the (F5) Run button in VBA so it didn't show me the error exactly.

When running the code from the macro it comes from the Userform call for which I have.


Sub Userform()
UserForm1.Show
End Sub


the userform1.show is highlighted yellow

Comment: You don't call the script with F5, it is triggered automatically when the form is opened (and it should run only when the form is open). Note that in your original code, you had a typo in the sub name and therefore the code was not triggered automatically.

Comment: I've since run F8 through the code. It would error the third time round. After checking through the form I realised my third combobox properties on "RowSource" still had a a tlb reference from first attempts. I have since deleted this and the code seems to be working now and all combo boxes are pulling the correct data.